# R Package Failing CRAN checks Because (r package) Matrix is not available for a dependency

Tags: r, r-package

I am developing my first R package. It is an extension of ggplot2 to work with survey data and the survey package.  It depends on ggplot2, dplyr, hexbin, and survey.

When I run a check on a machine with the dependencies, the check succeeds. However, it is failing checks on CRAN, and when I run it on R Hub I get the following error:
`Error : package ‘Matrix’ required by ‘survey’ could not be found`.

I tried adding Matrix to depends but it still does not work.

This is my description:

```
Package: ggsurvey
Type: Package
Title: Simplifying `ggplot2` for Survey Data
Version: 1.0.0
Author: Brittany Alexander
Maintainer: Brittany Alexander <balexanderstatistics@gmail.com>
Description: Functions for survey data including svydesign objects from the 'survey' package that call 'ggplot2' to make bar charts, histograms, boxplots, and hexplots of survey data.  
License: MIT + file LICENSE
Encoding: UTF-8
Depends: R (>= 3.5.0), ggplot2, Matrix, survey, hexbin, dplyr
Imports: stats
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 7.1.2
```

And my namespace:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(ggbarcrosstabs)
export(ggbarcrosstabs3d)
export(ggbarcrosstabs3d_svy)
export(ggbarcrosstabs_svy)
export(ggbarweight)
export(ggbarweight_svy)
export(ggboxweight)
export(ggboxweight2d)
export(ggboxweight2d_svy)
export(ggboxweight3d)
export(ggboxweight3d_svy)
export(ggboxweight_svy)
export(gghexweight)
export(gghexweight2d)
export(gghexweight2d_svy)
export(gghexweight3d)
export(gghexweight3d_svy)
export(gghexweight_svy)
export(gghistweight)
export(gghistweight2d)
export(gghistweight2d_svy)
export(gghistweight3d)
export(gghistweight3d_svy)
export(gghistweight_svy)
import(dplyr)
import(ggplot2)
import(hexbin)
import(survey)
```

The full github repository is here:  https://github.com/balexanderstats/ggsurvey Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Comment: Hi Brittany and welcome to StackOverflow!   Would you have a link to the RHub error log?

Comment: Dirk gave the solution to your question.  Some extra advice:  don't use `import(pkg)`, use `importFrom(pkg, fn1, fn2, ...)` so that you don't end up importing everything, only the things you need.  And I'd second Dirk's advice not to use `Depends` except in very special circumstances.  Those circumstances might apply for `ggplot2` and/or `survey`, but probably not the others.  (Use `Depends: pkg` only if you want everything in `pkg` available to the user when they attach your package.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I clone your repo (thanks for providing a link!) and I see

```
   Package in Depends field not imported from: ‘Matrix’
     These packages need to be imported from (in the NAMESPACE file)
     for when this namespace is loaded but not attached.
```

and that is just a 'Note' and not an error.  I see that you use `Depends:`, these days were we have `NAMESPACE` an `Imports:` is preferable.  And as the message say you seem to have an `import` for each of these packages but not `Matrix`.  Easy to add though on the same line in `R/importpackages.R`.  With that I check fine here (apart from an error in examples: `could not find function "ylab"` which I will leave for you.

```
edd@rob:/tmp/TEMP/ggsurvey(main)$ git diff
diff --git a/DESCRIPTION b/DESCRIPTION
index 5396e8b..3ff45af 100644
--- a/DESCRIPTION
+++ b/DESCRIPTION
@@ -7,7 +7,7 @@ Maintainer: Brittany Alexander <balexanderstatistics@gmail.com>
 Description: Functions for survey data including svydesign objects from the 'survey' package that call 'ggplot2' to make bar charts, histograms, boxplots, and hexplots of survey data.  
 License: MIT + file LICENSE
 Encoding: UTF-8
-Depends: R (>= 3.5.0), ggplot2, Matrix, survey, hexbin, dplyr
-Imports: stats
+Depends: R (>= 3.5.0)
+Imports: stats, ggplot2, Matrix, survey, hexbin, dplyr
 LazyData: true
 RoxygenNote: 7.1.2
diff --git a/NAMESPACE b/NAMESPACE
index 47f87db..ed44c86 100644
--- a/NAMESPACE
+++ b/NAMESPACE
@@ -24,6 +24,7 @@ export(gghistweight2d_svy)
 export(gghistweight3d)
 export(gghistweight3d_svy)
 export(gghistweight_svy)
+import(Matrix)
 import(dplyr)
 import(ggplot2)
 import(hexbin)
diff --git a/R/importpackages.R b/R/importpackages.R
index d4b487d..5e877fb 100644
--- a/R/importpackages.R
+++ b/R/importpackages.R
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-#' @import ggplot2 survey hexbin dplyr
+#' @import ggplot2 survey hexbin dplyr Matrix
 NULL
edd@rob:/tmp/TEMP/ggsurvey(main)$
```

My diff is below. Let me know if you would a like pull request with it.

*Edit:* And the `ylab()` issue goes away if you add `library(ggplot2)` to your examples. It then still fails over `data(api)` which may need another `library()` call.

Comment: It turns out something was wrong with CRAN (R-devel was not working) while I was trying to submit it. It now passes the check even without a Matrix depends.

Comment: Awesome.  Those things can and do happen and it is good know you have https://builder.r-hub.io/ (also via package `rhub`) along with the CRAN builder for windows and mac.  I keep a local R-devel build around, and also maintain two Docker images you can access.